# Regex for a string with multiple requirements

Tags: python, regex, verification, nsregularexpression

How do I write a regex which accepts a string 5-7 characters long, with small letters (can only zero or one duplicate) and 1 number in the middle of the string. If it is 6 characters long, a number can be either in the 2nd or 3rd position (assuming a string starts with an index of 0)

Acceptable: ab3bw, fdg5bde, qwe3gk, pu2auz

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is and it's quite a long one:

`(^[a-z]{2}\d[a-z]{2}$)|(^[a-z]{2}\d[a-z]{3}$)|(^[a-z]{3}\d[a-z]{2}$)|(^[a-z]{3}\d[a-z]{3}$)`

This just matches all the possible values.